# Can't get Unity Bootstrapper for MVC working

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api, unity-container

I have created a basic Web API project with a single controller and trying to use the Unity MVC Bootstrapper package from NuGet. Unfortunately when I try and visit the URL http://localhost/api/runtypes it throws the error

> {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Type
>   'SE.FlexApplication.WebApi.Controllers.RunTypeController' does not
>   have a default
>   constructor","ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentException","StackTrace":"
>   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(Type type)\r\n at
>   System.Web.Http.Internal.TypeActivator.Create[TBase](Type
>   instanceType)\r\n at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator)\r\n at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type
>   controllerType)"}

My controller class

```
public class RunTypeController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly IStaticTypesRepository _staticTypesRepository;
        private readonly IDataModelConverter _dataModelConverter;
        private readonly IBusinessModelConverter _businessModelConverter;

        public RunTypeController(IStaticTypesRepository staticTypesRepository, IDataModelConverter dataModelConverter, IBusinessModelConverter businessModelConverter)
        {
            _staticTypesRepository = staticTypesRepository;
            _dataModelConverter = dataModelConverter;
            _businessModelConverter = businessModelConverter;
        } 

        public RunType[] Get()
        {
            return _staticTypesRepository.GetRunTypes().Select(r => _dataModelConverter.Convert(r)).ToArray();
        }

        public HttpResponseMessage Post(RunType type)
        {
            _staticTypesRepository.AddRunType(_businessModelConverter.Convert(type));
            _staticTypesRepository.Save();

            var response = Request.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created, type);

            return response;
        }
    }
```

And the Unity activator

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(SE.FlexApplication.WebApi.App_Start.UnityWebActivator), "Start")]
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.ApplicationShutdownMethod(typeof(SE.FlexApplication.WebApi.App_Start.UnityWebActivator), "Shutdown")]

namespace SE.FlexApplication.WebApi.App_Start
{
    /// <summary>Provides the bootstrapping for integrating Unity with ASP.NET MVC.</summary>
    public static class UnityWebActivator
    {
        /// <summary>Integrates Unity when the application starts.</summary>
        public static void Start() 
        {
            var container = UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer();

            FilterProviders.Providers.Remove(FilterProviders.Providers.OfType<FilterAttributeFilterProvider>().First());
            FilterProviders.Providers.Add(new UnityFilterAttributeFilterProvider(container));

            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
        }

        /// <summary>Disposes the Unity container when the application is shut down.</summary>
        public static void Shutdown()
        {
            var container = UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer();
            container.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Unity Config class

```
public class UnityConfig
    {
        #region Unity Container
        private static readonly Lazy<IUnityContainer> Container = new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() =>
        {
            var container = new UnityContainer();
            RegisterTypes(container);
            return container;
        });

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the configured Unity container.
        /// </summary>
        public static IUnityContainer GetConfiguredContainer()
        {
            return Container.Value;
        }
        #endregion

        /// <summary>Registers the type mappings with the Unity container.</summary>
        /// <param name="container">The unity container to configure.</param>
        /// <remarks>There is no need to register concrete types such as controllers or API controllers (unless you want to 
        /// change the defaults), as Unity allows resolving a concrete type even if it was not previously registered.</remarks>
        public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            try
            {
                //container.RegisterInstance<IUnitOfWork>(new ProdUnitOfWork());

                container.RegisterType<IEventRepository, EventRepository>();
                container.RegisterType<IModelRepository, ModelRepository>();
                container.RegisterType<ISecurityRepository, SecurityRepository>();
                container.RegisterType<IStaticTypesRepository, StaticTypesRepository>();

                container.RegisterType<IDataModelConverter, DataToModelConverter>();
                container.RegisterType<IBusinessModelConverter, ModelToDataConverter>();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);                
            }
        }
    }
```

It seems like the Controller isn't picking up that it should be using the Unity Dependency resolver for constructor injection. I've followed all the steps on the tutorials online. Have I missed something basic?

Comment: _It seems like the Controller isn't picking up that it should be using the Unity Dependency resolver for constructor injection._ Actually, it's using the IoC container. it seems more like the types were not registered in the container used for resolution. Just as a routine check: are all the dependencies of `StaticTypesRepository `DataToModelConverter` and `ModelToDataConverter` (and their own dependencies) registered ?

Comment: Hmm the IUnitOfWork was needed for the StaticTypesRepository, so changed to uncomment the line above so no other secondary dependencies were not registered. Now I checked just at the end of the Start() method above and all the required types were created and registered. But when I navigate to the /API/RunType URL it tries to create the RunTypeController still with an empty constructor - ie it gives the same error and if I add a default constructor to the controller, it goes into it straight away

Comment: what about resolving the controller explicitly _from the IoC_  right after you finished registering all the types ?

Comment: If I add var c = container.Resolve <RunTypeController>(); after all the registrations, it resolves the RunTypeController correctly and calls the IOC constructor with injections. Is there a factory somewhere that MVC uses to create controllers when requested that needs to be overridden or updated to resolve the Controllers using Unity rather than just create blank ones?

Comment: Well, not exactly a factory, but there's the `BuildUnityContainer` method on the Bootstrapper. It is called by the ASP.Net plumbing and it returns your configured container. (see http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-dependency-injection)

Comment: I think from the comments that you have probably covered this but be aware that this is the error you will see if an exception is thrown in the constructor for your dependencies when they are instantiated. (or dependency cannot resolve a subsequent dependency as mentioned by Fabio). Something I've experienced and the exception is misleading in such a case. It had me spend a lot of time concentrating on Unity when the issue was elsewhere.

Comment: I think the resolution is working, as I try var c = container.Resolve <RunTypeController>(); which is the type of Controller being created by MVC, I try this in the bootstrapper after the types are registered and it creates fine with all dependencies. It is only when MVC tries to automatically create the controller when I visit the API url, it doesnt work

Comment: Even stranger, now if I put a break in the IOC constructor for my controller and just run the project, while it is initialising it actually goes into the constructor and has all the dependencies passed through correctly. But this is just on application startup before the website displays. I then get the home page, then try to navigate to /Api/runtype and thats when it throws the error without going into the IOC constructor. So something to do with the website interaction side of things?